# Does infinitesimal generator fully encode SDE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

When does the infinitesimal generator completely and uniquely encode its associated stochastic process?

For an Ito diffusion specifically, it would seem to do so, except maybe up to a rotation of the diffusion matrix coefficient.

Comment: I think there's really two questions here: when does the infinitesimal generator determine the semigroup, and when does the semigroup determine a Markov process?

Comment: @Ian Thanks :) Googling based on that led me to [Feller processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller_process), for which that seems to be true. And since solutions to SDEs (with Lipschitz continuous coefficients) are Feller processes, I guess that answers my second question for those cases. (though correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: If the coefficients of the SDE are unbounded, the solution is not necessarily a Feller process; you need some additional assumption in this case. (If you are only interested in the case of **bounded** Lipschitz continuous coefficients, then everything works fine.) For more information see https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02286

Comment: @saz Interesting; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments, for an Ito diffusion specifically, if $dX_t$ has *bounded, Lipschitz continuous coefficients*, then it is a Feller process, which implies that its infinitesimal generator fully encodes it.

Anyone who wants to comment on more general cases are welcome to do so! :)